# Yandex Карты API 2.0 : как можно прикрепить Панорамы и Воздушные панорамы

Tags: яндекс-карты, яндекс-карта-api

Панорамы и Воздушные панорамы, в документации **API 2.0** не видел примеры с панорамами,
можно ли добавить их на карте?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На данный момент через `API` пока никак. Только если таким образом:

[image]